# sshd service fails to start : ssh.service failed because the control process exited with error code

Tags: linux, ssh

I'm not sure why it isn't starting or why its preventing me from connecting, i get this error:

```
root@vmi: "# sudo service ssh status
ssh.service OpenBSD Secure Shell server
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2022-11-27 09:47:47 CST; 4min 58s ago
Docs: man: sshd (8) man: sshd_config(5)
Process: 446 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t (code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION)

Nov 27 09:47:47 vmi.contaboserver.net systemd[1]: ssh.service: Scheduled restart job, restart>
Nov 27 09:47:47 vmi.contaboserver.net systemd[1]: Stopped OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Nov 27 09:47:47 vmi.contaboserver.net systemd[1]: ssh.service: Start request repeated too qui>
Nov 27 09:47:47 vmi.contaboserver.net systemd[1]: ssh.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 27 09:47:47 vmi.contaboserver.net systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenBSD Secure Shell server. lines 1-12/12 (END)
```

Comment: In my case, I found useful this entry, it is an issue related with "NO HOSTKEY AVAILABLE". Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

Run `journalctl -xe` and paste the output here. There should be more information, most likely your port is already in use by something and sshd cant bind to it.